# Is there a way for Vim to re-source all the startup files without quitting and re-starting?

Tags: vimscript

I write a lot of Vim plugins.   When I make an edit to a plugin's .vim file, I'll often just quit Vim and restart it to test it.

In some cases, I would like to avoid quitting and restarting Vim.   I know I could `:source ...` the specific .vim file in my plugin that I've edited, but I'd be happy to know if there's a way to re-source all the startup files without quitting and restarting Vim.

I realize that some .vim files are written to exit early if they're sourced a second time, but that's okay for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you insist… `execute('scriptnames')->split("\n")->map({_, v -> split(v, ': ')[1]})` gives you all the scripts. You can then `map(scripts, {_, v -> execute('source '.v)})`. But this seems odd.

You could also `:runtime plugin/*.vim plugin/**/*.vim` if it's just plugins you're interested.

Then there's `:Runtime` from tpope's scriptease plugin, which is great for the case you described about `:source`ing a file.

Comment: I'll start using the `:Runtime` command.   It does correct tab-autocompletion at the command line too!     I've been using `:Scriptnames` and `:PP` from that plugin for a while, but did appreciate `:Runtime` until now.